# How to use parent object in listeners?

Tags: extjs

I have a simple example :

```
   test =  Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
       store: Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {
            listeners: {
               'load' : function() {  }
       })
    })
```

How to use grid object "test" in load listeners ?

Comment: You've got the `test` variable right there in the `load` function's parent scope so you can reference it directly.  Or am I misunderstanding your question?